# Dedicated IP vs Default IP

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, ip

We're in the process of moving over our Marketing Cloud account to 2.0 and through this process I've figured out that all our child accounts use the Account Default IP Address even though there are options for Private Address in the 'Delivery Profiles' section.

My question is if we're already using these Defaults is there any reason we would want to move over to a Private Domain in 2.0? And if we didn't can we transfer our current IP Address over to 2.0 even though its the 'Account Default' and therefore I assume not a Dedicated IP address.

Comment: Hi Hailee, can you [edit] this question to clarify what part of the Salesforce ecosystem or product suite you are working in? You can add one or more appropriate tags as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your new 2.0 environment is on the same stack (e.g. S1) as your existing one, you can indeed use same dedicated IP as you have now. You need to request this with support or your Salesforce account executive.

Account default IP address can still be your dedicated one. The option for selecting IP is for cases where multiple IP addresses are available in the same account. You are also mixing Private Domain and IP addresses. You can have a Private Domain regardless of whether you have a shared or dedicated IP address.

What is more decisive for what you should do, is your email volume. If you are sending above 250.000 email per month, you must use dedicated IP. If you send less than 100.000, a shared IP is recommended, as your email volume might not be substantial to keep your IP warm.

Without knowing any of the above details, it is indeed difficult to provide a decisive recommendation in your case.

Comment: This helps alot! We have varying sizes of send list depending on the brand so sounds like it would make sense to use a shared IP on some of the smaller brands. If were using a shared IP address and our email volume goes over 250,000 per month do you recommend moving over to a private ip address and warming it up or just staying on the shared one? Also can you share a private IP Address across multiple private domains/business units?

Comment: @HaileeMarcinek - then you should use one dedicated IP across across multiple business units (and private domains). This is indeed best practice. Remember to upvote/accept the answer if it has been helpful.